# Performance Improvement (Generating Random String of any length)

Tags: java, string, random

Generate a random string of any particular length. I know this question has been asked many times, I wrote this code below, I just wanted to know is there any better approach then the below code I wrote? Or we can make the below code more efficient?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = randomString(25);
    System.out.println(s);
}

public static String randomString(final int length) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Random r = new Random();
    String subset = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int index = r.nextInt(subset.length());
        char c = subset.charAt( index );
        sb.append( c );
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you know the length ahead of time, setup the StringBuilder with a capacity:

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);

This alone eliminates the unnecessary resizing of the internal array within the StringBuilder.

That being said, you're probably better off using a char[] array instead of StringBuilder, and just represent subset as a char[] as well.

```
private static final char [] subset = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();

char buf[] = new char[length];
for (int i=0;i<buf.length;i++) {
  int index = r.nextInt(subset.length);
  buf[i] = subset[index];
}

return new String(buf);
```

There's some subtle gains to be had here by avoiding some function call overhead to "charAt" and "append".  As well as eliminating some of the memory and allocation time overhead for the StringBuilder.  In general, if you know the size of a string you are building, it's a bit more efficient to work directly with the char arrays.

Comment: this is a better answer, because it doesn't need the `ensureCapacity` method that the `StringBuilder` uses every time it needs in the `append` call.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, the chances are that you probably don't *need* to improve this method's performance.  The chances are that the method is not called often enough that optimizing it will make a noticeable difference to the overall performance of the application.  You should **profile** your application before optimizaing at this level, otherwise you risk wasting time on stuff that makes no difference.

Secondly, even if this is a worthwhile optimization, you still need to profile your application to figure out which optimizations work best ... and whether the optimization effort has actually made any difference.

---

If (hypothetically) I was to attempt to make this go as fast as possible, I'd try this:

```
private static final char[] subset = 
        "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
private static final Random prng = new Random();
...
public static String randomString(final int length) {
    char[] chars = new char[length];
    final int subsetLength = subsetLength;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int index = prng.nextInt(subsetLength);
        chars[i] = subset[index];
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

In summary:

1. Don't create a new `Random` instance each time. This is probably this biggest optimization, because creating the instance typically involves a system call to get a random seed.
2. Don't use a `StringBuilder` when a `char[]` works just fine.
3. Avoid the (small) overhead of `charAt`.
4. Hoist once-off tasks out of loops and method calls, where possible.

(Note that points 3. and 4. could turn out to be not worthwhile; i.e. the JIT compiler could be smart enough to do identical optimizations for you ... if you just let it.)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than working with `String`s, you can cast `int` to `char` and make use of it directly.

```
// 36 total alpha-numeric characters
int size = 36;

for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    // num is an integer from 0-35
    int num = r.nextInt(size);

    if (num < 26) {
        // Then we add a lowercase character
        sb.append((char)('a'+num));
    } else {
        // then we add a digit 0-9
        sb.append((char)('0'+(num-26)));
    }
}
```

Other possible optimizations:

1. Work with a `char[]` with fixed size rather than a `StringBuilder`.
2. Define your `subset` string to be `static` and `final`.

Of course, these optimizations are pretty trivial and won't have much impact on your program in the context of this question.

---

### Edit:

If you need to generate a random `String` with a fixed set of characters, then the approach I mentioned above won't work. You'll have to work with a `String` containing the characters as you did in your post.

Comment: It won't work if you want to generate random string with a fixed set of characters.

Comment: Sorry, I was being stupid. I fixed it... still editing though :P.

Comment: Sorry, this is a little messy... but hopefully you get the idea :P. It's more efficient working with the primitive type `char` instead of creating/searching a `String`.

Comment: I ran your code and returned me a String with lots of whitespaces. Are you sure to have tested it?

Comment: Oops... I changed `num-26` to `'0'+(num-26)` and now it works as expected. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Create a random string using only the specified string and the length.
you use [RandomStringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html).
if you want to generate a random string [RandomStringUtils#random](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html#random%28int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20char%5B%5D,%20java.util.Random%29)
for examples:specified string and length is 25

```
private static final SecureRandom RANDOM = new SecureRandom();
private static final char[] PASSWORD_CHARS=("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz").toCharArray();
String passwd=RandomStringUtils.random(25, 0, PASSWORD_CHARS.length, false, false, PASSWORD_CHARS, RANDOM);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to minimize the calls to the random generator, you can produce 5 characters from each random integer. But this implementation only works for your precise  36-character set: `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` (see [Integer.toString() Javadoc](http://goo.gl/dFVB7)). 
And it is improbable that the obscurity of this implementation can compensate the perfomance gain.

```
private static final int range = 36 * 36 * 36 * 36 * 36; // 36^5 is less than 2^31
private static Random rand = new Random();
private static String zeroes="00000";

public static String generate(int length) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length+5);
    while (sb.length() < length) {
        String x = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(range), 36);
        if(x.length()<5)
            sb.append(zeroes.substring(0, 5-x.length()));
        sb.append(x);
    }
    return sb.substring(0, length);
}
```

The zero appending guarantees that the characters are uniformly random (without it, the character `0` would appear with slighly less frequency than the others).